# Classification, timeseries with different lengths and more than 1 feature (more than 1 time series per individual)

Tags: classification, time-series, clustering

What are the primary options regarding classification problems with time series with more than one feature and different lengths? So far I've read of k-means with dtw, but haven't seen it applied to more than one feature.

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) (DTW) could also be generalized to the case of *multivariate* time series, as in your case. There are at least two ways of generalization:

1. DTW$_I$ where each *feature/dimension* is treated *independently* (the subscript $I$);
2. DTW$_D$ where each *feature/dimension* is treated *dependently* (the subscript $D$).

I would not call $k$-means a classification algorithm: it is a clustering one.

The paper that presents the two can be found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5668684/).

Finally, as for classification of multivariate time series, you could use the *similarity* score provided by either DTW, and use a similarity/distance/instanced-based algorithm for clustering such as $k$-NN (e.g., $1$-NN). If you are interested in the state-of-the-art for classification of multivariate time series, you should read [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10618-020-00727-3) paper.